# UWP: Using ScaleTransform on WebView to scale/zoom contents

Tags: c#, webview, uwp, scaletransform, rendertransform

I am trying to use ScaleTransform to shrink a WebView, while scaling (zooming) the contents properly.  i.e., If I scale the WebView to 50% of the size using ScaleTransform, the contents should likewise scale to 50% zoom level, so you can see the same contents as before, just shrunk to fit the new size of the WebView.

I know it's possible, because the AdControl does properly scale its contents when you apply a ScaleTransform, and the AdControl internally uses a WebView control to display the ad.

Example code that works with an AdControl:

```
double scale = 0.75;
ad.RenderTransform = new TransformGroup() {
    Children = {
        new ScaleTransform() { ScaleX = scale, ScaleY = scale }
    }
};
```

If that same code is applied to a WebView control, it does shrink the size of the control, but the contents are clipped instead of shrunk.

Properly scaling the control's contents should **not** require the use of JavaScript injection or any other "kludgy" approaches, since it is highly doubtful that Microsoft's AdControl would use such techniques.  It should all be able to be handled in the XAML or code-behind (C#).

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I used  `<WebView Source="https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/default.aspx">
            <WebView.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform ScaleY="0.5" ScaleX="0.5"/>
            </WebView.RenderTransform>
        </WebView>` to test. The web page was shrunk normally. See [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBWxW.png).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I think it might be the content within the WebView I'm trying to scale down that is causing a problem.  I can't post publicly about exactly what the content is, but it contains an iframe that may have some kind of HTML/CSS coding that is preventing the content from scaling down as I scale down the entire WebView.  I wonder if there is some way to override that behavior?  The only thing I could think of would be to render a WebView brush on a Rectangle object and then scale that, but I imagine doing that would make the HTML static and unresponsive (just like a screen cap)